# Storing image in cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, gdi

I have a image handler but it keeps throwing errors

I don't know if I am inserting the image wrongly into the cache or retrieveing it the wrong way. I keep getting buffer null if I try to use the stream.

any ideas?

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {          
        _imageController = new ImageController();

        //Use ImageUrl to request image from external site
        string imageUrl = CastAide.AsString(context.Request["imageUrl"], String.Empty);
        //Use imageGuid and pageid to get image from user response upload
        string imageGuid = CastAide.AsString(context.Request["image"], String.Empty);
        int pageId = CastAide.AsInt32(context.Request["pageId"], -1);
        string subFolder = CastAide.AsString(context.Request["sub"], String.Empty);
        //Use ImageVaultId to return an imageVault Image
        int imageVaultId = CastAide.AsInt32(context.Request["imageVaultId"], 0);
        //Width and height determine the image size rendered
        int width = CastAide.AsInt32(context.Request["width"], 200);
        int height = CastAide.AsInt32(context.Request["height"], 200);
        bool resizeNoCrop = CastAide.AsBoolean(context.Request["resizeonly"], false);

        string cacheKey = "";
        Bitmap image = null;

    // Generate cache key
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(imageGuid))            
        cacheKey = String.Format("{0}_{1}", imageGuid, "guid");                           
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(imageUrl))            
        cacheKey = String.Format("{0}_{1}", imageUrl, "url");                              
    else if (imageVaultId > 0)            
        cacheKey = String.Format("{0}_{1}", imageVaultId, "vault");                 

    // Load from cache
    if (context.Cache[cacheKey] != null)
    {           
        // Load from cache
        //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])context.Cache[cacheKey]);
        //image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
        image = context.Cache[cacheKey] as Bitmap;                             
    }
    else
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(imageGuid))
        {
            // load file from the local file store
            FileInfo fi;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(subFolder))
                fi = new FileInfo(_imageController.GetFilePath(subFolder, imageGuid));
            else
                fi = new FileInfo(_imageController.GetFilePath(pageId, imageGuid));

            if (fi.Exists)
                image = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile(fi.FullName);
            else
                image = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageNotFoundPath"]);
        }
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(imageUrl))
        {
            // load file from the internet
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                image = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
                response.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                image = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageNotFoundPath"]);
            }
        }
        else if (imageVaultId > 0)
        {                   
            string filePath = ImageVaultUtility.GetSourceFileName(imageVaultId);
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);

            if (fi.Exists)                    
                image = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile(fi.FullName);                    
            else                    
                image = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageNotFoundPath"]);                    
        }

        // Insert image into cache
        context.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, image, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);    
        }


        if (resizeNoCrop)
            ImageUtility.ApplyResizeTransform(ref image, width, height, true);
        else
            ImageUtility.ApplyCropAndResizeTransform(ref image, width, height);

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        image.Dispose();

    }
```

when retrieving the cache the following is happening:

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what error is being thrown and at which line of the code?

Comment: Are you attempting to retrieve the image within the 10 seconds that it is available for? `context.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, image, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10), ...` means the image will be removed from the cache 10 seconds after it is inserted.  As @comptent_tech mentioned, we need better info regarding the exceptions to help you much further...

Comment: have made edit showing problems. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep a valid image in the cache, you should not do the `image.Dispose()` call. This will basically release unmanaged GDI+ resources, but keep the image reference in the cache, and GDI+ will not be happy on the next call.

Do the Dispose call only prior to removing it from the cache (if ever you need to remove it from the cache) or at expiration time only.

Comment: this might be true but it did not fix the problem above.

Comment: @okenshield - To investigate more, a full stack frame of the ArgumentException would help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for image caching.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CachingImagesInASPNET.aspx

Comment: The linked article is about controlling image caching on the client site whereas the question in hand is about caching images on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

By default when a bitmap image is created image is left unfrozen in case your app wants to update or modify the image. Under the covers the system also retains what thread created the bitmap and disallows other threads to modify the image. You are getting the error because multiple threads are trying to access the image in cache. What you have to do before adding it to cache is this:

```
if(image.CanFreeze) {
  image.Freeze();
}
```

this will make the file static and unmodifiable, and allow the framework to pass the Image to other calling threads without issue.

Be very careful because a busy server with many image files can run out of memory if you are caching them without some sort of management.